# iOS : mismatched translation

Tags: ios, xcode, translation, nslocalizedstring, mismatch

I'm trying to add a language to my app and it was working until now. After a day to try to understand what's happen, I give up.

This is my problem :

My base language is english (development language) and my other language is french. I have some localizable strings in Main.storyboard and Localizable.strings.

Export is working, no problem with that but when i'm trying to import Xcode i have some warning : "Mismatched translation" and then if i import, nothing change :  [I have no information about this Mismatched Translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbd3i.png)

Somebody have any idea to help me ??

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I struggle with the same problem. In my case, Xcode tells me I have 1 mismatched translation, and it shows me a window listing all the 450 string translations. There is no obvious way to pinpoint the one that has the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the "mismatched translation" was caused by a mismatch between the base language (English) string in my code (the value: parameter of the NSLocalizedString call) and the English string in the XLIFF file being imported. That shouldn't normally happen, but in this case the source code had been modified after the XLIFF was exported and before the translated XLIFF was imported. Still, it would be awfully nice if Xcode would pinpoint which one of my 450 translation units had the problem!

Comment: This has been changed, latest Xcode can pinpoint which translations mismatched for original source.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the 'mismatched translation' was caused by some extra white space that obviously confused my either Xcode or my xliff editor...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone faces this issue with latest Xcode version, basically, mismatch means, you changed the source from exported file, you should change(translate) only the target, as changing the source makes mismatch with current source in Xcode, hence no effect as if xcode could not see translation for the source it has of main lang as you changed source by translating it with the target!

Kindly check the attached image, you should only translate Target if it needs translation, the source should not be touched!
[image]